# Confused by Fetch as Googlebot behaviour

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, fetch-as-google

I have a site that I 'm trying to index and I am a bit confused by what I should expect to see in the result of the `Fetch as Googlebot` tool. The site uses hashbangs, so according to Google it *should* be crawlable by substituting hashbangs with `?_escaped_fragment_`. However, the results of the fetch don't show the actual content. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer, and it turns out that `Fetch as Googlebot` works as it should. My problem was that whenever I detected an `_escaped_fragment_` url, I redirected to static content. The thing is, the tool does not understand redirections (possibly with good reason). When I fixed the problem Ajax crawling worked like a charm.

Comment: How did you fetch the corresponding HTML? I'm currently trying to make an AJAX site with #! indexable with _escaped_fragment_, but I'm lost as to how I'm supposed to detect the urls with _escaped_fragment_ and provide the corresponding HTML.

Comment: I used phantomjs to produce the static pages, and a simple controller action to serve them from a folder 'static' in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the "fetch as Googlebot" tool really uses the same programs that run its search engine spider. It's more likely a standard web page fetch using their user agent string.

So all it will do is fetch the page as you supply it. If you're having indexing problems then make sure you have genuine links to you hashbang URLs. If the entire site including home page is Javascript then you may have issues.